# Flutter:flutter app doesn't work after build apk

Tags: flutter, apk

**Hello finally I finished developing my app using flutter it's was Depends on API data when I developing  I was using my mobile to running it's doing good but when I need to output apk using communed 
    `flutter build apk`  i'ts display but when make login to app using data from API i'ts not working  but when do run app everything working good … what the problem ???**

**massages showing me when do build apk**

```
You are building a fat APK that includes binaries for android-arm, android-arm64, android-x64.
If you are deploying the app to the Play Store, it's recommended to use app bundles or split the APK to reduce the APK size.
    To generate an app bundle, run:
        flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64
        Learn more on: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle
    To split the APKs per ABI, run:
        flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --split-per-abi
        Learn more on:  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                                                                                  Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider-1.6.5\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\pathprovider\PathProviderPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated A
PI.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Removed unused resources: Binary resource data reduced from 46KB to 37KB: Removed 20%
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                     413.1s (!)
√ Built build\app\outputs\apk\release\app-release.apk (19.3MB).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add on android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: If it helped you, please accept it as the correct answer to prevent others from commenting on the same thing.